# Understanding \cventry from moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I'm using [`modercv`](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/moderncv-cv-and-cover-letter) class with [`casual`](http://www.latextemplates.com/templates/curriculum_vitaes/7/cv_7_casual.pdf) style.

At the end there is the preview of 1st page. Note the *Education* section. It contains *date* and *description* and it is produced with the command

```
\cventry{2011--2012}{Masters of Commerce}{The University of California}{Berkeley}{\textit{GPA -- 8.0}}{First Class Honours}
```

By the other hand if we insert longer *date* (e.g. `{12/2011--12/2012}`) it does not fit in a single line, as we can see:

[image]

So I decided to edit the `cls` and increase a little bit the space reserved for the *date*. But I'm not able to do this. I can not understand the definition of the command `\cventry`:

```
% makes a typical resume job / education entry
% usage: \cventry[spacing]{years}{degree/job title}{institution/employer}{localization}{optionnal: grade/...}{optional: comment/job description}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{}
```

If I'm not wrong, `\cventry` has 7 arguments and the 1st is optional with default value `.25em` and the others are textual.

So why the year is typeset as in a tabular, I mean, it has fixed width.

I also checked `moderncvstylecasual.sty` but no mention to that command.

---

[image]

Comment: You have to adjust `\hintscolumnwidth` with `\setlength` :)

Comment: In most styles the first column is a p-column in a tabular. The exact location of the definition depends on the style and the moderncv version. In the newest version you find them in the moderncvbodyXXX.sty.

Comment: @HarishKumar, what a shame! It is written `%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column`. But I din't see where this command is used in the `cls` or `sty` files. Now, after your comment I found it in `moderncvcompatibility.sty`.

Comment: And as Ulrike says, You can find the definition (not needed in this case for you) of `\cventry` in `moderncvbodyi.sty` (line 106 if you want).

Comment: @HarishKumar, in the `zip` file I got I don't have any file which contains `body` in its name.

Comment: Then it is not newest. Check your distro instead (if you have upto date installation). With miktex: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aFeY7.png

Comment: @HarishKumar, thanks. I didn't know that all those templates comes from TeXlive 2015. I have all of them. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=62&t=26592

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments.