# Modify the \cventry

Tags: moderncv

I'm using moderncv document class with classic style. Instead of the normal formatting that I receive for

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\name{first}{last}


\begin{document}
\makecvhead

\cventry{09/2016 - 05/2017}{Tutor in Mathematics and Physics}{Personal tutor for High School Students}{NY, USA}{}{} 
\end{document}
```

which is  the following:[image]

I would like to have the cv entries with a new line after the "title" (in this case "Tutor in Mathematics and Physics").

I tried with `\hfill` and so but it doesn't work. But also checking: [Understanding \cventry from moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263742/127163) I couldn't find where `\cventry` is defined.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead edit your question to include a minimal compilable document that people can play with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the following does something closer to the expected output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\name{first}{last}

\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{,\newline {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}

\begin{document}
\makecvhead

\cventry{09/2016 - 05/2017}{Tutor in Mathematics and Physics}{Personal tutor for High School Students}{NY, USA}{}{} 
\end{document}
```